# How can I put a program listing in a beamer column?

Tags: beamer, listings, columns, adjustbox

I want to use a program listing in a beamer `columns` environment, changing slightly the with of the listing, if necessary. In the other column, some explanation comes. The code below shows my attempt. If `breaklines=true`, then of course long lines are wrapped, at the boundary of the green box. If `breaklines=false`, then the long line goes out of the green box, but `\maxsizebox` considers the width of the green box, i.e. the long line overlaps with the right column. In either case, the green box does not fill up the column width. It looks like that option `linewidth` increases the width of the green box, but it is not maximized by 
`\maxsizebox`.

How can I tell that the green box fills the available column width (i.e. in this case 0.4\columnwidth) and the longest line does not go out of the green box?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\listingboxname
\begin{columns}
\column{0.4\columnwidth}
    \lstset{ %breaklines=true,
     linewidth=1.2\textwidth,
     backgroundcolor=\color{green}}
    \begin{lrbox}{\listingboxname}
    \begin{lstlisting}
int sumvec(int v[N])
{
    int i, sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      sum += v[i];
    return sum;
}  
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{lrbox}
    \maxsizebox{\columnwidth}{\textheight}
        {\usebox\listingboxname}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
Just some text
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

This results in
[image]

Comment: Within the `lrbox`, use a `minipage` of width `\linewidth` or `\columnwidth`. Give some feedback (we don't have `lst/sumvec.c` to try this ourselves...

Comment: Please make your MWE independent of files we don't have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For listings which are smaller than the column width, your solution with the background colour works perfectly fine (see second frame in the example).

For listings which are wider you could use `adjustbox` to resize them to the column width. To add the background colour I use a `\colorbox`, but as listings are problematic content for a `\colorbox` I hide the listing by storing it in a `lrbox`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newsavebox\listingboxname

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{lrbox}{\listingboxname}
                \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth, margin=0pt}
                \begin{lstlisting}
int sumvec(int v[N])
{
    int i, sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) longer line to test
      sum += v[i];
    return sum;
}  
                \end{lstlisting}
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{lrbox}
            \colorbox{cyan}{\usebox\listingboxname}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            Just some text
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
                \begin{lstlisting}[linewidth=\textwidth,
                     backgroundcolor=\color{cyan}]
int 
{
}  
                \end{lstlisting}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            Just some text
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe. Could you please comment, what you are doing? Till now I knew \lrbox as some temporary store, which then must be activated; the \adjustbox protested when I attempted to fill it with a listing, I also wonder how the rest of my constructions will like the fragile environment. Also, why my solution was wrong. (I mean if you can give some references)

Comment: @katang I added a bit of explanation. As for the `fragile` argument of the frame, it's necessary  if you want a listing in a frame.  The problem with your solution was, that the resizing only saw a box of `1.2\textwidth`, which was resized to fit into the column, but the lines of the listings where longer then that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no provision for automatically setting the width of a listing to the widest line, as far as I know.

Set the listing to a width that fits the longest line, then resize the box.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\newsavebox\listingboxname

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{columns}
\column{.4\textwidth}
\lstset{
   %breaklines=true,
   backgroundcolor=\color{green},
   linewidth=1.5\columnwidth, % maybe it fits
}
\begin{lrbox}{\listingboxname}
\begin{lstlisting}
int sumvec(int v[N])
{
    int i, sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      sum += v[i];
    return sum;
}  
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{\usebox{\listingboxname}}

\column{.6\textwidth}
Just some text

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution fits the column  width to the listing witdh, I want the opposite. I want to set the listing to its normal width (what would be without columns), and that resulting picture scaled into the column.

Comment: @katang OK, that's clearer now. New solution on line.